# ¿Como hacer que los campos de una tabla se llenen por defecto con valores de otra tabla?

Tags: python, web2py

Esta es mi tabla facturacion

```
db.define_table('facturacion',
                Field('numero_comprobante', 'string'),
                Field('numero_cotizacion', 'reference cotizaciones'),
                Field('cliente', 'reference clientes'),
                Field('marca_gg', 'reference marcas_definiciones'),
                Field('contacto_cliente', 'reference contactos'),
                Field('razon_social_gg', 'reference razones_zociales_gg'),
                Field('fecha_facturacion', 'date'),
                Field('estado_facturacion', 'reference estados_facturacion'),
                Field('tipo_comprobante', 'reference tipos_comprobantes'),
                Field('moneda', 'reference monedas'),
                Field('razon_social_nombre_completo_cliente', 'string'),
                Field('ruc_dni_ce_cliente', 'string'),
                Field('direccion_fiscal_cliente', 'string'),
                Field('detraccion', 'boolean'),
                Field('monto_detraccion'),
                Field('fecha_recepcion', 'date'),
                Field('sub_total', 'float'),
                Field('descuento', 'float'),
                Field('sub_total_venta', 'float'),
                Field('impuesto_igv', 'float'),
                Field('total_venta', 'float'),
                Field('nota', 'text'),
                format='%(numero_comprobante)s')
```

y esta es mi tabla clientes

```
define_table('clientes',
                Field('cliente', 'string'),
                Field('creacion', 'date'),  # , default=now, writable=False
                Field('tipo_cliente', 'reference tipos_clientes'),
                Field('razon_social', 'string'),
                Field('tipo_doc_id', 'string'),
                Field('direccion_fiscal_cliente'),
                Field('fecha_aniversario', 'date'),
                Field('area_negocio', 'reference areas_negocios'),
                Field('estado_cliente', 'reference estados_clientes'),
                Field('medio_captacion', 'reference medios_captacion'),
                #Field('direccion_principal', 'string'),
                Field('telefono_contacto', 'string'),
                Field('email_contacto', 'string'),
                Field('url', 'string'),
                Field('nota', 'text'),
                format='%(cliente)s')
```

El problema esta en que cuando seleccione un cliente la tabla facturacion ...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos de la tabla facturacion que sean de clientes debe llenarse de manera automatica, en otras palabras al seleccionar un cliente en facturacion algunos campos deben llenarse o aparecer de forma automatica.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son esos campos? El único campo que veo que puede estar relacionado es `Contacto Cliente`. Lo que me parece raro es que `Contacto Cliente` aparece como un select en tu formulario, pero en la tabla solo veo `telefono_contacto` e `email_contacto` y ambos son `string`

Comment: Los campos que deben salir por defecto en facturacion al seleccionar un cliente son: razon social, ruc o dni y direccion fiscal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí tienes que utilizar AJAX porque la funcionalidad que quieres tener se ejecutará una vez que el sitio ya esté en el navegador del cliente.

En tu controlador debes crear un método que será ejecutado cada vez que selecciones un nuevo cliente, y este método va a devolver un nuevo HTML Helper SELECT que tú vas a construir, y este nuevo select reemplazará al select que actualmente se está mostrando en el sitio.

Ahora, dado que la función AJAX recibe sólo un target como parámetro, lo ideal sería que este método sea parametrizado y, según el parámetro, te devuelva el nuevo select que deseas.

Finalmente en tu HTML, en donde muestras tu formulario, debes agregar una función de JavaScript.

Por ejemplo:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function onChangeCliente(){
    eval("ajax('{{=URL('default', 'metodoControlador', vars=dict(nuevoSelect='razonSocial'))}}', ['cliente'], 'formulario_razonSocial')");
    eval("ajax('{{=URL('default', 'metodoControlador', vars=dict(nuevoSelect='dni'))}}', ['cliente'], 'formulario_dni')");
    eval("ajax('{{=URL('default', 'metodoControlador', vars=dict(nuevoSelect='direccionFiscal'))}}', ['cliente'], 'formulario_direccionFiscal')");
}
```

En donde `['cliente']` es el atributo `name` del select de clientes, y `'formulario_razonSocial'`, `'formulario_dni'` y `'forulario_direccionFiscal'` son los atributos `id` de los selects target que van a cambiar cada vez que se elija un nuevo cliente.

Para obtener estos nombres utiliza Firebug o las herramientas para desarrolladores que vienen incluidas en Google Chrome.

En el controlador sólo deberías crear el siguiente método:

```python
def metodoControlador(nuevoSelect):
    cliente = db(db.clientes.id == request.vars.cliente).select().first()
    if nuevoSelect == 'razonSocial':
        return SELECT([OPTION(cliente.razon_social)])
    elif nuevoSelect == 'dni':
        . . .
        . . .
        . . .
```

Y listo, los selects cambiarían cada vez que cambies de cliente.